# Copying node_modules into a dockerfile vs installing them

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, dependencies, node-modules

I’ve been tasked with dockerizing our Node app at work. When it comes to node_modules, I’m in a bit of a disagreement with our lead dev.

He is advocating for something like this in the dockerfile. His reasoning is that the docker image will be more deterministic, and on that point I don’t entirely disagree with him.

```
COPY node_modules ./
```

I am advocating for something like this. My reasoning.. that’s essentially how everyone on the internet says to do it, including the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) and the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/language/nodejs/build-images/). I wish I was arguing from a technical perspective, but I just can’t seem to find anything that specifically addresses this.

```
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
```

So who is right? What would be the downsides associated with the first option?

Answer (score 11):

I'd almost always install Node packages from inside the container rather than `COPY`ing them from the host (probably via `RUN npm ci` if I was using npm).

If the host environment doesn't exactly match the container environment, `COPY`ing the host's `node_modules` directory may not work well (or at all).  The most obvious case of this using a MacOS or Windows host with a Linux container, where if there are any C extensions or other binaries they just won't work.  It's also conceivable that there would be if the Node versions don't match exactly.  Finally, and individual developer might have `npm install`ed an additional package or a different version, and the image would vary based on who's building it.

Also consider the approach of using a multi-stage build to have both development and production versions of `node_modules`; that way you do not include build-only tools like the `tsc` Typescript compiler in the final image.  If you have two different versions of `node_modules` then you can't `COPY` a single tree from the host, you must install it in the Dockerfile.

```sh
FROM node AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm install

FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN npm ci
COPY --from=build /app/build /app/build
CMD ["node", "/app/build/index.js"]
```